# Higher Order Functions (Eloquent JS) that provide new types of control flow?

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I'm working through EloquentJS Chapter 5 High-Order Functions and I'm having trouble fully understanding the parts where he's giving examples of functions that create new functions. Where I'm having trouble is understanding functions that provide new types of control flow:

```
function unless(test, then) {
    if (!test) then();
}

function repeat(times, body) {
    for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) body(i);
}

repeat(3, function(n) {
    unless(n % 2, function() {
        console.log(n, "is even");
    });
});
// → 0 is even
// → 2 is even
```

It seems to me that it's saying if the test argument is false, then run the function passed as the second parameter.

Since 0 % 2 and 2 % 2 == 0, wouldn't the function passed as "then" NOT run? In other words, shouldn't it be returning odd numbers? Where am I going wrong with this? I feel like I'm being particularly dense.

This is how I'm reading the "unless" function:

```
//if (!(n %2)) then run the function.
```

I have no idea how I convinced myself the opposite of what the function is actually doing. Thanks for your time.

Comment: The `if` will pass because `0 == false`

Comment: OH MY GOD 
RIGHT thank you. I was assuming that a modulo operation expression returning 0 remainder would be true.

Thank you thank you thank you

Comment: I was wondering if someone who kindly elaborate on the code above please? I'm trying to understand about higher order functions. `n` is a parameter  to the outer function.

Comment: @elclanrs I was wondering if you would kindly elaborate on the above code for me please? I would really appreciate it. I don't understand how new types of control flow works with higher order functions. Thanks for your time!